# Can we have another custom close reason?

Tags: discussion

[What actions make the game award you a Mist Tank?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24945/what-actions-make-the-game-award-you-a-mist-tank)

This question just looks awkward with the close vote.

> put on hold as off-topic by Retrosaur, Zommuter, deutschZuid,
>   ChrisHateZ, OrigamiRobot 4 hours ago
>
> This question does not appear to be about videogames or videogame
>   consoles, within the scope defined in the help center.

But it IS about video games, it's just that the question is outdated.

Could we have a custom close message as "Closed, the question is outdated due to a recent patch/fix." or something along the lines of that?

It just looks plain weird with how it looks right now.

Comment: We're limited to three custom close reasons right now, I believe.  Regardless, I don't think we close enough questions in this scenario to make it viable.

Comment: @fbueckert If needed, we can always ask for more slots; SO has 5. Asking on meta is the proper way to bump the limit.

Comment: Why not just type in a custom reason when you go to close the question?

Comment: @Fluttershy That's exactly what happened. See [Retrosaur's comment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24945/what-actions-make-the-game-award-you-a-mist-tank#comment170977_24945)? That's the written-in close reason that every voter picked. What's displayed on the question is the default catch-all off-topic description. Maybe we should insert the "winning" comment in there somewhere to make it clearer what happened. Of course, if the comment isn't very clear, it might make things worse in some cases.

Comment: @AnnaLear Oh. Huh... I thought it automatically put the user-written close reason in the description. I never noticed that it didn't.

Comment: We just need too localized back, is all.

Comment: Same for this question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119469/how-to-stop-valve-from-spamming-me-with-dota-2-gifts the wording in the comment is good, but the on hold reason is kinda screwy.

Comment: I'm thinking a custom reason like "This question is no longer applicable to the current state of the game". Basically, a fancy way to say "Stuff in this question no longer exists in the game"